# spark dataframe: date formatting not working

Tags: apache-spark

I have a csv file in which a date column has values like 01080600, basically MM-dd-HH-mm.

I want to add a column in dataframe which shows this in a more readable format.
I do :

```
spark.sql("SELECT date...")
      .withColumn("readable date", to_date(col("date"), "MM:dd HH:mm"))
      .show(10)
```

But readable date is returned null.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is your intended output

Answer (score 0):

While formating or converting to `date` or `timestamp` you need to provide the  `date_format` as is following your pattern , example in your case you need to modify your format as below and further which can be formatted depending on the final format you wish your date col to take using [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html)

References to various patterns and parsing can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

#### To Timestamp

```
sql.sql("""
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP('01080600','ddMMhhmm') as date,
    DATE_FORMAT(TO_TIMESTAMP('01080600','ddMMhhmm'),'MM/dd hh:mm') as formated_date
""").show()

+-------------------+-------------+
|               date|formated_date|
+-------------------+-------------+
|1970-08-01 06:00:00|  08/01 06:00|
+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: original data is MMddHHmm

Comment: the same parsing format will work with `H` in place of `h` as well. The key thing is to adjust date_format  accordingly to your data